# How to filter out unapproved documents from KQL search results in Office365 Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have been banging my head over this for a couple of days, I am trying to filter out documents in my kql query that haven't been approved by my workflow.  My workflow is a standard publishing workflow, but no matter if the file is approved or not, it still shows up in the search results.

I've read that you're supposed to map the `ows__ModerationStatus` crawled property to a managed property, but the `ows__ModerationStatus` crawled property is missing.  I've tried re-indexing the document library with the workflow on and have waited for days for it to show up.  I've searched `moderation`, `ows` and multiple terms to find it.  I even searched `ows` and went through each property individually and it hasn't been crawled.  Can anyone give me assistance on this?  I've tried 2 separate tenants and both aren't giving me this crawled property.  Is there a better way of doing this or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out my problem here, the `_ModerationStatus` field was hidden so i had to create a custom script to unhide the column and then it was crawled